# Unity menus don't display properly

Tags: unity, menu

Posted this a while back on the Ubuntu forums, but never got a reply, and I still haven't found a way to fix it myself.

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. Or some reason, menus (File, Edit, etc) aren't displaying properly. Specifically, the text is almost unreadable because it is nearly thesame color as the background (Though for some reason it acts differently for different menus, as shown below. Pictures (I'm a new user, so I can't post pic:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hmQov.png]

The ones with the darker text can't be clicked on because nothing is selected to use them on. The lighter ones (almost invisible against the white background) are clickable.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FN8EB.png]

This problem also exists with the buttons on notification dialog boxes, though I don't have a screenshot. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm running Unity on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try System Settings > Appearance > Theme > Default

If previous installation had tweaks to the theme maybe this could interfere.

You could also try create a new profile and see if that changes anything

Comment: Thanks, it must have been changes I made in 12.04 screwing stuff up, I found some stuff in my .themes folder for the one that was being problematic, removed it, and repaired some other files I had messed up while trying to fix it, restarted Unity, and it works perfectly.